# Autofilter multiple worksheet where a column does not contain a value

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

enter image description hereI have a spreadsheet that contains multiple worksheets, sometimes it may be up to 20 sheets, all the columns are the same across the sheets, I want to be able to do a macro to autofilter each sheet on Column X to exclude zero.

I think I might have done it but, when you click on the filter drop down it doesn't put any ticks in, so do i
I trust that its worked correctly, not sure.

Any advise would be appreciated.

Code I created.

```
Sub Apply_Diff_Qty_Exclude_Zero()
'
    Dim xWs As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each xWs In Worksheets
        xWs.Range("A2").AutoFilter 24, "<> 0"
    Next
End Sub
```

[Screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOMlo.jpg)

[Screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WmStt.jpg)

Comment: Can't you just scroll through and see that no zeroes are present? Not sure what you need help with to be honest.

Comment: Thanks for the response Caleb, I can, but it can be tens of thousands of lines each sheet, so was hoping to save time.

Comment: Could you add screenshots to your post of what the filtering looks like?

Comment: Screenshots added.

Comment: Thanks. If you filter by the zeroes, are those zeroes you would expect to be there? Just curious. I am trying to understand exactly what it is you need. Do you think you can make a mockup of your spreadsheet (something similar that I can physically play with)

Comment: I'm just trying to remove any lines where Column X contains a zero, I will make a mockup with 20 lines per worksheet.

Comment: Okay thanks. Does "contain a zero" mean a zero in the number, or zero itself. Sounds like a dumb question but clarifying details like this will help me help you.

Comment: its zero in the number, basically i want to leave lines where the value is larger or greater than Zero (0).

Comment: I have mockup, but not sure how to post it on here

Comment: You can post it to google sheets and link it to me. I can copy the data from there

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1D6s9P7QIfjP_QLIOsA3l_8mmY5s0IGh8a51P14jKsac/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Access requested. Next reply will be my findings / solution if I have one.

Comment: Request granted, thanks

Comment: Please confirm if my code works by making a backup on your document before running it.

Comment: did you confirm this code works for what you needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code worked for me on the test document. I double checked and it only removed the rows with zero. Please let me know if this works.

```vb
Sub Apply_Diff_Qty_Exclude_Zero()
    Dim xWs As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each xWs In Worksheets
        xWs.AutoFilterMode = False 
        xWs.Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=24, Criteria1:="<>0" 
    Next
End Sub
```

[image]

Modified the code to be infinitely expandable. To add more criteria, copy the line xWs.Range.... and replace the criteria you need. Don't forget to change the Criteria1 to Criteria2 and etc for more rows.

```vb
Sub Apply_Diff_Qty_Exclude_Zero()
    Dim xWs As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each xWs In Worksheets
        xWs.AutoFilterMode = False
        xWs.Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=">0"
        xWs.Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=22, Criteria1:="=0"
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Works a treat, thanks.

Comment: using the same data, is it possible to code for 2 criteria ? column V =0 and column G is >0, this would be great if you can.

Comment: Yes, you can. Assuming you meant X = 0 (the original question was for column x to be 0, then you code replace this line `xWs.Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=24, Criteria1:="<>0" ` with the one i put at the bottom of the original answer.

Comment: This would be a different scenario to the original, on this one I would need column V to be zero and column G to be greater than zero.

Comment: I will give the above a go, thanks

Comment: rich if you want to modify the code to work with column v, change the first field from 24 to 22

Comment: Hi Caleb, tried the code, but get a compile error. Code used -

Comment: xWs.Range("A2").AutoFilter Field:=22, Criteria1:="<>0", _
        Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="=0", Field:=7, Criteria3:=">0"

Comment: Fails on Criteria3

Comment: ok allow me one moment to troubleshoot.

Comment: Rich please see the original answer - modified the code to allow for infinite additions to criteria. should be as simple as changing the numbers for future filters.

Comment: You should be able to modify this code for future cases by simply changing the field and criteria. hope this does you well. Take care

Answer (score 0):

try

```
Sub FilterColumnX()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        With ws
            If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
            Dim lastRow As Long
            lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "X").End(xlUp).Row
            .Range("X2:X" & lastRow).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>0"
        End With
    Next ws
End Sub
```